# WP и htaccess. Перенаправление на новый домен

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Что-то туплю. Приклеил новый домен к сайту. В настройках WP и в БД поменял все ссылки на новый домен. В htaccess написал:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-site\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Главная страница кидает на новый домен, все норм. Но остальные страницы продолжают работать как на старом домене, так и на новом. Как сделать переадресацию всех страниц старого домена на новый?

Comment: Неправильно сделал. Читай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: Прочитал. Что именно не правильно? Сайт у меня работает, в БД все поменял. Про переадресацию в той теме ничего нет, старый домен должен оставаться рабочим, но переадресовываться.

Comment: Тобишь формально все ссылки вида https://old-site.ru/?page=1, https://old-site.ru/stranica/ и тд должны редиректить на https://new-site.ru/?page=1, https://new-site.ru/stranica/ и тд

Comment: Как "поменял" ссылки? Файлы физически остались на месте или перемещены на др хостинг/аккаунт? Вот если бы прочитал - ты бы ответил на эти важнейшие вопросы.

Comment: Я просто приклеил новый домен, ничего никуда не переносил.

Comment: Воот.. Я же говорю - неправильно сделал. Надо брать плагин и менять ссылки в базе. Повторю:  **не вручную**, а плагином, исправляющим сериализованные данные.

Comment: В БД все заменено через "Найти и заменить". На новом домене все работает. Если я отклею старый домен, то все будет работать как надо. То есть по факту сейчас сайт одиннакого работает на обоих доменах. Мне нужна просто переадресация со старого на новый.

Comment: Нечитатель, не понимаетль :( Я всё. Всё что можно было - рассказал, объяснил.

Comment: Да это Вы меня не понимаете. WP сам перенесен и отлично работает. Мне нужна только htaccess переадресация.

Comment: 1. в первой строке не хватает флага `NC`, раз уж вы хотите действительно все запросы перенаправить. 2. вы где проверяете? Исключаете кэш браузера?

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Проверял в приватной вкладке. Психанул и скопировал файлы в другую директорию, домен новый туда кинул и со старого 301 редиректом кинул на новый (когда были в 1 директории, то шло циклическое перенаправление). Сейчас все хорошо работает)